# Check if an specific app is being used by user

Tags: java, android

I've wrote a foreground service and I would like to check what app that user is using (for "using", I mean what app is active and not running in background). Example: if the user is using Instagram, I would like to return true if packageName equals Instagram package's name.

This is what I've tried but no lucky because I only see my App and I've opened Chrome to check If Chrome process were going to appear in list:

```
public static boolean isAppRunning(final Context context, final String packageName) {
    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (procInfos != null)
    {
        for (final ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : procInfos) {
            if (processInfo.processName.equals(packageName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The object *procInfos* were always with a single element: my app. How can I solve it?

Comment: "I would like to check what app that user is using" -- there may be many apps that the user is using. For example, on Android 7.0+, Android supports multi-window. "How can I solve it?" -- hopefully, you can't, except perhaps on rooted devices or via device admin/device owner APIs. Google has been tightening down access to this information, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: I was reading some topics facing same problem. That code won't work on 5.1+.

Comment: @CommonsWare Since this app will run on phones from our company, do you have any idea or link how to use Device APIs?